# Caffe's input data normalization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, normalization, caffe

As far as I understood if I want to apply normalization of data [0, 255] to [0, 1), I can pass a parameter of scale: 0.00390625 in the *transform_param* of *prototxt* file. However, what if I would want to perform normalization of data to [-0.5, 0.5] (in order to have 0 mean distribution) at *prototxt* level?

Consider my *train_val.prototxt* file looks like below:

```
transform_param {
  mirror: true
  crop_size: 227
  scale: 0.00390625
  mean_file: "some_mean_file.binaryproto"
```

Mathematically speaking, I think it looks like below:

```
 normalized value = (input pixel value / 255) - 0.5
```

but I'm clueless how to map into the scale value of *transform_param* since the scale value has no notion of negative value (signed value). Perhaps, Caffe has different mechanism to achieve this (instead of doing it via scale operation).

From my understanding obtained from Udacity's lecture on deep learning, it mentioned that it is a good practise to always normalize the input so as to have a *0* mean. Can I relax this sort of guide? Any significant effect if I would ignore it?

Comment: I've looked into it but seems no such mechanism that I can normalize the input to [-0.5, 0.5].

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Shai. I've overlooked, not looking from that perspective ;-). Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @Shai: Perhaps, if you don't mind,  you can help copy the above thought of yours in an answer box so that I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L410-L431) comments on `TransformationParameter`

> ```
> // For data pre-processing, we can do simple scaling and subtracting the
> // data mean, if provided. Note that the mean subtraction is always carried
> // out before scaling.
> ```

mean subtraction is done **before** scaling, therefore, after subtracting `mean_file`,  your data is approx in range `[-128. 128]`. scale it by 1/256 and you are done, your data should be roughly in range `[-.5, .5]`.